# Is there an @BeforeClass hook in cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I'm running an sql script that connects to the database and I run it in an @Before hook However this takes a while I only need to run the script once. The tests are taking forever to run as when it goes through my data table it runs the script before the test again. Is there a way around this as I only need to run this script once.

> @Before
>       public void setup() throws IOException, SQLException {
>
> ```
>     if (!clean){
>         DatabaseConnection.getStatement();
>         cleanUp();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Use a static boolean flag. Set it initially to false. Check in the Before for the value of the flag.If false run the script and set the flag to true. Next time this will not run.

Comment: I will give this a try thank you.

Comment: If you do not need this hook to run for all scenarios you should limit its scope by adding relevant tags to the hook.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515

Answer (score 0):

Hand rolling a before behaviour as Grasshopper suggests is a good idea. It will solve your issue until the day you are able to setup your environment in smaller, disjunctive steps.

To me, it feels risky to depend on one, big setup. What happens if the features are executed in different order? If they don't depend on the execution order then that's great. But there is a risk that they do depend on each other and that you miss it until one day when everything fails.

Comment: In this instance the features don't depend on each other they are separate entities.